# Why can't I open an ssh session sometimes?

Tags: ssh

I often use ssh, so I configured 'myhost' in the `~/.ssh/config` file in such a way I only have to type `ssh myhost` and enter passphrase for key to connect to the server. Usually I just connect to the server, but sometimes after entering this command I'm not even asked for the passphrase, ssh just suspends and prints only one new line (enter).

Is this a problem with server performance or is it my problem and can I solve it?

Comment: Try verbose output `ssh -vvv` to see. I would guess it is a network issue.

Comment: Ok, ssh stuck at `debug1: Connecting to <somehost> [someip] port 22.`.

Comment: I have had issues with reverse DNS lookups slowing down connections, so try disabling that

Comment: I disabled DNS and still have this problem. Websites on this server and my e-mail account are working fine.

Comment: It might be distant DNS (on target server) trying to figure out your incomming IP.

Comment: Nice, can it be fixed somehow?