# SSH sends different keys with this same configuration

Tags: ssh

I've already asked [the question why sometimes I can't log in to SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586573/why-cant-i-open-an-ssh-session-sometimes). At the time I didn't know why. However, I wrote to the server administrator and he told me that connection is blocked by sshguard. In addition, he sent me a list of my login attempts ( `sudo grep publickey\ for\ <myusername> /var/log/auth` command output). It looked like this:

```
.
.
.
May 12 21:38:16 boss sshd[3003]: Failed publickey for <myusername> from
<myip> port 24057 ssh2: RSA
SHA256:hqddgd...VHhFM
May 12 21:38:16 boss sshd[3003]: Failed publickey for <myusername> from
<myip> port 24057 ssh2: RSA
SHA256:1NwYXJ66...+U5MqJ0
May 12 21:38:21 boss sshd[3003]: Accepted publickey for <myusername> from
<myip> port 24057 ssh2: RSA
SHA256:A6uQ/jb...I9UjXzc
May 12 21:39:29 boss sshd[3151]: Failed publickey for <myusername> from
<myip> port 23837 ssh2: RSA
SHA256:hqddgd...VHhFM
May 12 21:39:30 boss sshd[3151]: Failed publickey for <myusername> from
<myip> port 23837 ssh2: RSA
SHA256:1NwYXJ66...+U5MqJ0
.
.
.
```

Whenever I tried to log in I sent keys that had checksums in order: hqddgd...VHhFM, 1NwYXJ66...+U5MqJ0, A6uQ/jb...I9UjXzc. The third time my connection was always accepted. I don't know if this is a coincidence, but I have exactly three keys in the ~/.ssh/ directory. In addition, the ~/.ssh/config file looks like this:

```
Host <server to which I want to log in>
    HostName <nice domain>
    User <myusername>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<myusername>

Host <another server>
    HostName <nice domain>
    User <another username>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<another username>
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From man ssh_config:
IdentitiesOnly
Specifies that ssh(1) should only use the authentication identity and certificate files explicitly configured in the ssh_config files or passed on the ssh(1) command-line, even if ssh-agent(1) or a PKCS11Provider offers more identities.  The argument to this keyword must be yes or no (the default).  This option is intended for situations where ssh-agent offers many different identities.

Just try and add it to your ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host <server to which I want to log in>
    HostName <nice domain>
    User <myusername>
    IdentitiesOnly=yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<myusername>
```

Comment: You probably meant the `IdentitiesOnly=yes` option. `IdentitiesOnly` causes error. I don't know if it works anyway. I can't log in yet, and administrators already finished job. I don't have access to logs myself, especially not logged in ...

Comment: You are correct! Sometimes I should read what I c&p. ;-)